# How to display in my view if 2 or more rows are returned but in my view I want to display single column where primary key(npp) same

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm confused how
I want  to display like this (just click in link)
there's view and database
[this my view which I want](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bb7k4ck7l2prrzh/boom.JPG?dl=0)

Explanation:
If in database I insert in table

```
npp:87  
tgl_masuk:20/02/2009    
nama:ulung  tgl_mulai:01/01/2015
tgl_pengajuan:03/01/2015    
tgl_selesai:08/01/2015  
lama:5  
bagian:1
```

this data will display on column bagian=1 and the field value=5
etc

this my view now

```
<thead>
<tr>

<th>npp</th>
<th>Nama </th>
<th>Tanggal Masuk </th>
<th>Tanggal Mulai</th>
<th>Tanggal Selesai</th>
<th>Lama</th>
<th>Bagian</th>
<th>tanggal Pengajuan</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php  if(!empty($query)) { foreach($query as $row) { ?> 
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold">
<span class="label label-warning"><?php echo $row->npp ?></span>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row->nama_pegawai ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->tgl_masuk ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row->tgl_mulai ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->tgl_selesai ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->lama ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->bagian ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->tgl_pengajuan ?></td>
</tr>

<?php }} ?>
```

controller

```
function index($limit='',$offset=''){
    if($this->session->userdata('LOGIN')=='TRUE'){
    $this->load->model("Cutitahun_Model"); 
    $data['judul']='Histori Cuti tahun Pegawai';
    /* VAGINATION */
    if($limit==''){ $limit = 0; $offset=10 ;}
    if($limit!=''){ $limit = $limit ; $offset=$this->offset ;}
    $data['count']=$this->Cutitahun_Model->countcuti_tahun();   
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Cuti_tahun/search/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['count'];
    $config['per_page'] = $this->limit;    
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="pg">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';       
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    /*----------------*/
    $data['query']=$this->Cutitahun_Model->getListCuti($limit,$offset);
    $data['view']='Cuti_tahun/hist_cuti';
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }else {
    redirect('home/loginPage');     
    }

 }
```

model

```
function getListCuti($limit='',$offset=''){
        $menus='';
        $judul=$this->input->post('judul');
        $status=$this->session->userdata('STATUS');
        $addTag="";
        if($status!=0){
        $addTag="where t_pegawai.nik='".$this->session->userdata('NIK')."'";    
        }
        $query=$this->db->query("select t_cuti.status as status,t_cuti.id as cutiid,t_pegawai.id,t_pegawai.nik,t_pegawai.nama,m_jabatan.nama_jabatan,m_unit_kerja.nama_unit_kerja,m_cabang.nama_cabang from t_cuti
        LEFT JOIN t_pegawai ON t_pegawai.nik=t_cuti.nik
        LEFT JOIN m_jabatan ON t_pegawai.kd_jabatan=m_jabatan.kd_jabatan
        LEFT JOIN m_unit_kerja ON t_pegawai.kd_unit_kerja=m_unit_kerja.kd_unit_kerja
        LEFT JOIN m_cabang ON t_pegawai.kd_cabang=m_cabang.kd_cabang
        $addTag
        ORDER BY t_cuti.id DESC LIMIT $limit,$offset");
         if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
                $menus[]=$data;
            }
            return $menus;
        }

    }
```

Comment: this not my full view, sorry , I,m fixed that.
so do you know solution about my problem?

Comment: You need to write your query to get the data structure you want, but since you haven't shown the query it is impossible to help.

Comment: Ah sorry again... I'll  my model and controller

Comment: I have added my model and controller